# Specify which java type to decode an embedded document to

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a simple java type

```
public class Type1_ {

    private int number1;
    private int number2;

    public Type1_(int number1, int number2) {
        this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
    }

    public int getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }

    public int getNumber2() {
        return number2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Type1_{number1=" + number1 + ", number2=" + number2 + '}';
    }

    public static Type1_ random() {
        return new Type1_(new SecureRandom().nextInt(), new SecureRandom().nextInt());
    }
}
```

Created a simple `Codec<Type1_>` for this type (with loggers to know when or if they are being used)

```
public class Type1_Codec implements Codec<Type1_> {
    @Override
    public Type1_ decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        reader.readStartDocument();
        final int number1 = reader.readInt32("number1");
        final int number2 = reader.readInt32("number2");
        reader.readEndDocument();
        final Type1_ type1_ = new Type1_(number1, number2);
        APP_LOGGER.debug(type1_);
        return type1_;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, Type1_ value, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeInt32("number1", value.getNumber1());
        writer.writeInt32("number2", value.getNumber2());
        writer.writeEndDocument();
        APP_LOGGER.debug(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Type1_> getEncoderClass() {
        return Type1_.class;
    }
}
```

Added the codec to a registry to be used in `MongoClient`

```
public class CustomCodecRegistriesFactory {

    public static CodecRegistry getDefault() {
        return MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
    }

    public static CodecRegistry getDefaultWithType1_() {
        return CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new Type1_Codec()), getDefault());
    }

}

public class MongoDBClientConfig {    
    public static MongoClient buildMongoClientWithCustomCodec(final CodecRegistry codecRegistry) {
        return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> {
                    builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(url(), port())));
                })
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .build());
    }
}
```

Created a test that uses a codec registry where the `Type1_Codec` is included and attempt to insert (encode) and read (decode) `Type1_`

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class Codecs {
    @Test
    public void demonstrate_simpleCustomCodec() {
        final MongoClient mongoClient = buildMongoClientWithCustomCodec(CustomCodecRegistriesFactory.getDefaultWithType1_());
        final MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db_" + new SecureRandom().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        final String collectionName = "col1";
        db.createCollection(collectionName);
        final MongoCollection<Document> col1 = db.getCollection(collectionName);
        int idCounter = 0;
        final String type1_field = "type1_";

        printTitle("Inserting Documents");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            /*Encoding is done at insertion*/
            col1.insertOne(new Document(ID, idCounter++).append(type1_field, Type1_.random()));
        }

        printDocumentMongoCollection(col1);
        printMongoCollectionJackson(col1);

        printTitle("Attempting Decoding");
        /*attempt decoding*/
//        final Type1_ type1_value = col1.find().first().get(type1_field, Type1_.class);
//        System.out.println(type1_value);
    }
}
```

The problem is in the decoding part.
How do i specify for MongoClient that i want a specific document to be decoded into `Type1_` type?

The commented out code will attempt to cast a `Document` to `Type1_` and will fail.

Answer (score 0):

use `db.getCollection(collectionName, Type1_.class)` to "type" your collection.  That should pull your codec in to play automatically for you.